# map<string, vector<string>> reassignment of vector value

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, assign

I am trying to write a program that takes lines from an input file, sorts the lines into 'signatures' for the purpose of combining all words that are anagrams of each other. I have to use a map, storing the 'signatures' as the keys and storing all words that match those signatures into a vector of strings. Afterwards I must print all words that are anagrams of each other on the same line. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string signature(const string&);
void printMap(const map<string, vector<string>>&);

int main(){
string w1,sig1;
vector<string> data;
map<string, vector<string>> anagrams;
map<string, vector<string>>::iterator it;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("words.txt");

while(getline(myfile, w1))
{
  sig1=signature(w1);        
  anagrams[sig1]=data.push_back(w1); //to my understanding this should always work,
}                                    //either by inserting a new element/key or
                                     //by pushing back the new word into the vector<string> data
                                     //variable at index sig1, being told that the assignment operator
                                     //cannot be used in this way with these data types
myfile.close();

printMap(anagrams);

return 0;
}

string signature(const string& w)
{
string sig;
sig=sort(w.begin(), w.end());
return sig;
}

void printMap(const map& m)
{
for(string s : m)
{
  for(int i=0;i<m->second.size();i++)
     cout << m->second.at();
  cout << endl;
}
}
```

The first explanation is working, didn't know it was that simple! However now my print function is giving me:
`prob2.cc: In function âvoid printMap(const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&)â:
prob2.cc:43:36: error: cannot bind âstd::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}â lvalue to âstd::basic_ostream<char>&&â
In file included from /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40:0,`
Tried many variations and they always complain about binding

```
void printMap(const map<string, vector<string>> &mymap)
{
for(auto &c : mymap)
  cout << c.first << endl << c.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::multimap`?

Comment: Original question: why was anagrams[sig1]=data.push_back(w1) not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anagrams[sig1]` will return a reference to a `vector<string>`. Rather than assign to it, you just want to `push_back` onto it.

```
sig1 = signature(w1);
anagrams[sig1].push_back(w1);
```

As your code is written right now, it's trying to *replace* the vector instead of add to it. For example, let's assume your input contains both `was` and `saw`, and that your `signature` sorts the letters of the string.

What you want for this case is:

1. read "was"
2. sort to get "asw"
3. insert "was" to get: `anagrams["asw"] -> ["was"]`
4. read "saw"
5. Sort to get "asw" (again)
6. insert "saw" to get: `anagrams["asw"] -> ["was", "saw"]`

With the code as you've tried to write it, however, in step 6, instead of adding to the existing vector, you'd overwrite the current vector with a new one containing only "saw", so the result would be just `anagrams["asw"] -> ["saw"]`.

As far as `printmap` goes: the items in the map aren't `std::string`s, they're `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`, so when you try to do:

```
void printMap(const map& m)
{
    for(string s : m)
```

...that clearly can't work. I'd usually use:

```
for (auto s : m)
```

...which makes it easy to get at least that much to compile. To do anything useful with the `s`, however, you're going to need to realize that it's a `pair`, so you'll have to work with `s.first` and `s.second` (and `s.first` will be a `string`, and `s.second` will be a `std::vector<std::string>`). To print them out, you'll probably want to print `s.first`, then some separator, then walk though the items in `s.second`.